# Problem with screen resolution on installing ubuntu in Lenovo Ideapad Z580?

Tags: graphics

I am using Lenovo Z580 Ideapad. First when I try to install Ubuntu it was always displaying a black screen with things like `no sdisk found` displayed on it. When I changed graphics to UMA I was able to install Ubuntu but on booting my screen is filled with lots of small squares with cursor. I am not able to do any thing in this.

What is wrong with my graphics settings what do I need to do to fix them?